# Having a for loop inside a jQuery append Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, append

**My Question** 
I am having trouble finding how to place a for loop inside a jQuery append method. Should it be a strong, should it be just there, how do I format the code so it works?

**My Code**

```
window.onload = function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#li22').append($('<table/>').append(for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {'$('#li22').append($(""));'}));
    });
}
```

Comment: @Archer Sorry. Will rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't put a `for` loop directly in the `append()` method. Secondly, don't put a document.ready event handler inside a window.onload handler - it's pointless.

Also, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve. You're appending a `table` to `#li22`, then appending nothing to `#li22` and returning that to the `table`...? As such the below is a general guide on how to use `append()` properly.

`append()` accepts a either string, so you should put the `for` *outside* the `append()`, like this:

```
$(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('#li22').append($('<table/>'));
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can provide a function to `append()` which returns the HTML to be appended. You can put the `for` in there:

```
$(function () {
    $('#li22').append(function() {
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        html += '<table></table>';
      }
      return html;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, a single append with a block of Html also offers considerably better performance.

Comment: Yes pretty stupid of me, i did rush the question but I still got the answer of this post and thus, you win the correct mark!

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute code inside of a function's argument. Therefor, the code must be formatted like:

```
window.onload = function () {

    $(function () {

        var tableTag = $('<table><table/>');

        $('#li22').append( tableTag );

        for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

            $( tableTag ).append( "" );

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       var string="<table>";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
        { 
           string += "what you need";
        }
        string +="</table>"
        $('#li22').append(string);
    });
```

Comment: That won't work. Not only is not functional, there is a syntax error.